# Link dimension from one datasource to Measure in another in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and I'm trying to make measures from one data set dependent on a Dimension in another.

[image: enter link description here]
So I'm trying to link Expenditures of 2000,2012 and 2013 of one data source with year dimension which has only three values (2000,2012 and 2013) in another data source

Basically at the end I just need one Average Expenditure with its value for the corresponding years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link the two data sources by year, you will have to picot the table to bring it from a wide format (having each year in a separate column) to a long format (having each year in a separate row).

In Tableau go to the Data Source tab and select the three Expenditure columns, then right click on the header and choose "Pivot data".
That should bring your data in the correct format:

```
CountryA 2000 XXX
CountryA 2012 YYY
CountryA 2013 ZZZ
CountryB 2000 AAA
...
```

You might want to rename your columns to `[Year]` and `[Expenditure]` for example and you will have to create a calculated field with `Right([Year], 4)` to get only the year out of your former field name.
Now you can click on "Data" in the menu on the top and select "Edit Relationship", there you can choose the field with the year in one data source and the newly created calculated field in the other data source.